# Why did George throw the book into his own suitcase?

Tags: silver-streak

In [*Silver Streak* (1976)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075223/) after spending the night with Hilly, in the next morning when George finds out about Professor Schreiner from the photo in his book and can't convince Hilly about what he saw the night before he gets irritated and throws it into his own suitcase.

It wasn't a random throw because he stands still for a second and looks at his suitcase. Why did he throw it into the suitcase? It was Hilly's book and he particularly expressed his lack of interest about it the night before. This looked like a dumb plot twist to me because later in the movie the book became important.

Answer (score 1):

The [script](https://thescriptsavant.com/movies/The_Silver_Streak.pdf) indicates that he threw the book in exasperation. It wasn't *specifically* into his suitcase, just in that general direction. The fact that the lid closed and the book ended up among his personal effects is obviously plot-relevant, but he didn't take the book on purpose.

> Leaning forward to gently touch her hair, he knocks the Rembrandt book off the chair. He picks it up and notices an envelope stuffed with papers sticking out from under the jacket cover. He pats the envelope back in place and is about to put it down when he turns it over to look at the author's picture on the back. He gasps with surprise for the picture of the grey-haired old man with the white goatee is the same man he saw hanging dead outside the window. The train lurches and George staggers. Turning quickly to Hilly, he shakes her awake.
>
> **GEORGE:** *Hilly! Hilly! Wake up. Look at this.*
> Hilly stirs and sits up, still half-asleep.
> **HILLY:** *What, what?...*
> She sees George and gives him a sexy, kittenish smile.
> **HILLY:** *Oh, hello, George.*
> **GEORGE:** *Hilly, the dead man I saw out the window last night — this is him!*
> Hilly seems interested for a moment till George shows her the back picture on the book. She looks at it with some confusion.
> **HILLY:** *George, that's my boss. That's Professor Schreiner.*
> **GEORGE:** *I know.*
> **HILLY:** *George, what time is it?*
> **GEORGE:** *It's after eight.*
> **HILLY:** *Eight! Wake me again after ten.*
> She closes her eyes and lies down, cuddling up to a pillow.
> **GEORGE:** *Hilly, this man has been murdered.*
> **HILLY:** *Yeah. Well.* (she thinks sleepily) *Why don't you go and discuss it with him and then come back here later and discuss it with me. His room is just past the diner. Room D.*
> **GEORGE** (exasperatedly) *Hilly...*
> **HILLY:** *Good night, George. You're a wonderful gardener.*
>
> **George walks away from the bed and paces to his side of the room. He looks at the book again and throws it into his open briefcase with such force that the lid closes over it.** He is not sure what to do. He looks at the window and finally makes up his mind. Taking his coat from his closet, he puts it on and exits.